# Invariance of gauge-fixing condition in background field method

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, yang-mills, gauge

In the Peskin & Schröder (chapter 16.6) they use the background field method and spilt the gauge field into an background field $A$ and a fluctuation field $\mathcal{A}$. Next they claim that
the Lagrangian (16.98) is invariant under the background gauge symmetry
$$A^a_\mu\rightarrow A^a_\mu+D_\mu\beta^a\tag{16.99a}$$
$$ \mathcal{A}^a_\mu\rightarrow \mathcal{A}^a_\mu-f^{abc}\beta^b\mathcal{A}_\mu^a\tag{16.99b} $$

(+ transformations of ghosts and fermions)
where $D$ is the covariant derivative constructed from the background field.
However I don’t see why the gauge fixing term
$D^\mu\mathcal{A_\mu^a}$ should be invariant under this transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. One trick is to rewrite the (infinitesimal) background gauge transformation (16.99) as
   $$\begin{align} 
   \delta_B A_{\mu} ~=~& [D_{\mu},\beta],\cr
   \delta_B D_{\mu} ~=~& -i[D_{\mu},\beta],\cr
   \delta_B {\cal A}_{\mu} ~=~& -i[{\cal A}_{\mu},\beta],
   \end{align} \tag{16.99} $$
   using the conventions (15.44) & (16.91). Here $[\cdot,\cdot]$ denotes a commutator or a Lie bracket depending on context.
2. The Lorenz gauge function $[D^{\mu},{\cal A}_{\mu}]$ therefore transforms covariantly
   $$ \delta_B [D^{\mu},{\cal A}_{\mu}] ~\stackrel{(16.99) + \text{Jac.id.}}{=}~ -i[[D^{\mu},{\cal A}_{\mu}],\beta]. $$
3. The gauge-fixing term
   $$\kappa\left([D^{\mu},{\cal A}_{\mu}],~[D^{\nu},{\cal A}_{\nu}]\right)$$
   is invariant under the background gauge transformation (16.99) because the [Killing form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form) $\kappa(\cdot,\cdot)$ is [associative/invariant](https://planetmath.org/invariantformliealgebras).